# Qt 5.9 Android storage permission in Marshmallow

Tags: android, qt5

I need to know how to ask permission for storage in android marshmallow and above in Qt 5.9.

There is a new API in Qt 5.9 release - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50759